# How to resolve "error code is 0x80070001"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web

I get the following error with the following stack trace. How do I resolve this?

> error code is 0x80070001

#### Stack trace

```
[Type] Error | [Source] AccountsServices:An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070001. | [Category] None | [Event] 0 | [User] | [Computer] VM2014.conduit.local | [Description] Message was not found: 0
_Duration=207593.75
Message:An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070001.
StackTrace: at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInParamsCollection()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetParams()
at BrandToolbar.Web.Profile.ConduitProfileModule.UpdateVar() in d:\conduit\RnD\Server\Infrastructure\Providers\Web\Profile\Dev\ConduitProfileModule.cs:line 119
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825127/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-incorrect-function-exception-from)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825127/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-incorrect-function-exception-from)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an issue with your application code, but probably your environment configuration. Are you using VMs?

You may or may not find this forum post helpful: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/698e2b2b-af59-4848-b041-4fbb11c5bb6b

Comment: A WBM snapshot might come in handy.
https://web.archive.org/web/20220925140554/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/698e2b2b-af59-4848-b041-4fbb11c5bb6b/an-error-occurred-while-communicating-with-the-remote-host-the-error-code-is-0x80070001?forum=winserverhyperv The original link does not work anymore.